# Concrete walkway work - considered acceptable?

Tags: concrete

Hello I just had a concrete walkway done and I feel like there are a few issues that are important enough to address with the contractor but I wanted a second opinion on what is acceptable and what is unacceptable.

The main issues I see are the risers of stairs are not finished well, and the bigger issue I see is there are some gaps and where the risers meet the runs, there's a weird Gap that slopes into one another.

Is all of this to be considered normal and acceptable work? My gut feeling tells me no but I wanted another opinion.

Thanks

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: it looks decent to me. they have to set it about level, so if the sides aren't level and even, they do the best they can. same as when the boards don't fit 100% flush against the wall because the wall is not flat or has pockets. if you paid top-of-the-line rates for the contracting, they could have patched and chiseled for you, but you can clean that up in an hour or two and it should last decades. don't forget to seal it. you also want slope and some gaps so that it drains quickly. does it form puddles from a hose down?

Comment: Risers rarely get the same finish as the treads pull the boards two early and it will sag two late and cannot finish at all. I know some contractors that tap the boards with a hammer and that is all the risers get. Trying to fill in an area with multiple angles, surfaces that are also locked in is tough, it is not the best job I have seen but it is far from the worst.

Comment: Was this the only bid you got? If not, was it the cheapest?

Comment: I got two bids. Both were about $300 apart from each other. This was the same concrete company that I had a positive experience with a few years ago. Both companies are positively reviewed online. Now that I answered your questions, can you answer mine?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based (or legal), but here are my $.02. The finish is poor. There should not be form lines nor rock pockets showing. Lines against other objects, such as the stone wall, should've been trowel cut to eliminate slag. There should be no woodgrain left from the forms. This looks amateurish and would not be acceptable to me.

Comment: Thank you isherwood for your thoughts. I paid about $5000 plus tax for the work which I thought was not cheap and which seemed to be competitively priced with other reputable companies.

Comment: I'd go in with an angle grinder and hammer/chisel to neaten the rough edges. That glop on the downspout pipe out to come off with just a hammer. For the price, I'd expect the contractor to have done the finish work. Course for that price, I'd have done it myself.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger thank you for your suggestions. For now I'm going to raise those issues with the contractor so that they hopefully improve the look before I have to do anything. If I had the time and the know how I could say the same thing but I have zero concrete experience!

Answer (score 2):

"Normal and acceptable" is subjective but should be thought about as being inversely proportional to how much you paid for the work.

The form boards need to stay in place until the concrete has set sufficiently to hold the vertical surfaces from sagging; this takes awhile. A craftsman would stay on site, testing the set and removing the boards at the earliest opportunity, then finishing the areas where the form boards were. I have seen this done with a wet wood float, a wet steel trowel, a light spray and a broom; all depends on the desired finish.

For private homes it has been my experience that the rough work on your job is the *exception*, nice finish work is the *norm*. Remember the old adage- "You get what you pay for".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jimmy for the opinions - I paid $5000 + tax which I think was not bargain basement and was competitive with prices from other reputable companies.

Comment: Prices vary by area, and the pics and description don't tell the whole story (demolition, excavation/groundwork, subsurface obstructions, accessibility, urgency, etc.), but for $5,000 I would expect better finish. Maybe you could dress the risers with decorative stone or tile...?

Comment: Toronto Canada, removal of old side walkway (probably about 30' length)